# Twenty Fourteen: Unsticky header after making header bigger

Tags: css, headers, theme-twenty-fourteen

I am using theme Twenty Fourteen, and to add a logo I made the header bigger with the following code:

```
 .header-main {
    min-height: 108px;
}
```

It works, but now the header isn't sticky anymore and I don't know why.  Can someone please explain why the header isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the theme's js.

in `/twentyfourteen/js/functions.php`:

```
    /*
     * Fixed header for large screen.
     * If the header becomes more than 48px tall, unfix the header.
     *
     * The callback on the scroll event is only added if there is a header
     * image and we are not on mobile.
     */
    if ( _window.width() > 781 ) {
        var mastheadHeight = $( '#masthead' ).height(),
            toolbarOffset, mastheadOffset;

        if ( mastheadHeight > 48 ) {
            body.removeClass( 'masthead-fixed' );
        }

        if ( body.is( '.header-image' ) ) {
            toolbarOffset  = body.is( '.admin-bar' ) ? $( '#wpadminbar' ).height() : 0;
            mastheadOffset = $( '#masthead' ).offset().top - toolbarOffset;

            _window.on( 'scroll.twentyfourteen', function() {
                if ( _window.scrollTop() > mastheadOffset && mastheadHeight < 49 ) {
                    body.addClass( 'masthead-fixed' );
                } else {
                    body.removeClass( 'masthead-fixed' );
                }
            } );
        }
    }
```

You can see it checks the height, and then if it's larger than 48, removes the `masthead-fixed` class from the body.

You could either

**a.** run some js that fires after functions.js:

```
$(body).addClass( 'masthead-fixed' );
```

**b.** force the site-header to be fixed via CSS:

```
.site-header
{
    postion: fixed;
}
```

Note in both cases, you'll likely need to add larger top margins to other content to push it down so the header doesn't cover it.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew, for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work, at least the second option with CSS. I have insufficient experience to implement the first option that you described. But meanwhile I think it's better to shrink the header to 48px before getting fixed. I mean after scrolling the logo schooled be minimized and the header should have a height of 48 px. I think this must be something like a fade-in-function. You know what I mean. And you know how to do it?

Comment: Oh, it works with CSS. (I just copied your code, but there was a misspelling...) But now happens what you described. I need to add larger top margins. How can I do it?